# How do I display my array that is of a structure type

Tags: c#, data-structures

```cs
public static Product[] LoadItems()
        {
            //method to return array contents of vending machine
            return new Product[] {

                new Product() { name = "Cheese", price = 2.0M },
                new Product() { name = "Salami", price = 1.5M },
                new Product() { name = "Kitkat", price = 1.0M },
                new Product() { name = "Fanta", price = 1.8M },
                new Product() { name = "Sharp hamburger", price = 4.3M },
                new Product() { name = "Coconut water", price = 0.8M },
                new Product() { name = "Crackers", price = 2.0M },
                new Product() { name = "Orange juice", price = 0.75M },
                new Product() { name = "Water", price = 0.6M }
            };
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //creates array named machine using LoadItems
            Product[] machine = LoadItems();
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the vending machine. The products available are:");
            for (int i = 0; i < machine.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(machine[i]);
            }
        }
```

I would like to display the items and prices, however I am unsure on how to do this.

I believe it may be an error with my formatting of `Console.WriteLine(machine[i]);`

Comment: While you could format the WriteLine, it may be better to override the `ToString` method in your `Product` structure.

Comment: `ToString` should be overridden to produce the *canonical* string form. Classes like this rarely have a canonical form. It's usually best left to the consumer (the code that holds a reference to the instance) to decide how it wants to present the data.

Comment: If the type wants to provide pre-fab forms, it can do that with a `ToString(string format)` method. Types like `int` and `DateTime` do this, for example. `int.ToString()` produces the canonical form of an integer as base 10 with no separators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
 Product[] machine = LoadItems();
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the vending machine. The products available are:");
        for (int i = 0; i < machine.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + machine[i].name + " Price:  " + machine[i].price);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to output an object, it has to be converted to a string. This is done via the `ToString()` method, which you can override.

For example

```
class Product
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Name: {0} Price: {1:0.00}", this.name, this.price);
    }
}
```

After you've done this, the console will display a more friendly string when you output the product.